# CISCO routing newby

Tags: cisco

[image]

I have an existing network 192.168.51.0 as in the top-right in the image

I have a new network that I need to hook up to this network. The new network comprises:

- 2x CISCO Routers (interfaces to existing network has IPs 231 and 232)
- 2x CISCO Switches (with trunk interconnect)
- A workstation (single ethernet port configured with 2 addresses ending in .10 on VLANs 192.168.11 and 13 )
- 2x servers (node1/2) with 4 ethernet ports each. they are bonded in pairs with each bond cross-connected to both switches (color coded to illustrate bond pairs). the one bond is on network 192.168.1.0 and the other bond has three VLAN IP addresses on the bond on VLANs 11, 12 and 13

All workstations and servers are running Linux if that matters.

My question is how to properly configure routing on the two routers so 192.168.51.10 can access 192.168.11.10 or 13.10 ?

More specifically what should the *ip route* and *router rip* parts be ? I have already

*ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.51.254*

Interfaces are of the form

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0                                                                                               
 ip address 192.168.1.254 255.255.255.0                                   
 ip nat outside                                                           
 ip virtual-reassembly in                                                 
 duplex auto                                                              
 speed auto                                                               
!                                                                         
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.11                                           
 encapsulation dot1Q 11                                                   
 ip address 192.168.11.254 255.255.255.0                                  
!                                                                         
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.12                                           
 encapsulation dot1Q 12                                                   
 ip address 192.168.12.254 255.255.255.0                                  
!                                                                         
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.13                                           
 encapsulation dot1Q 13                                                   
 ip address 192.168.13.254 255.255.255.0                                  
!                                                                         
interface GigabitEthernet0/1                                                                                                
 ip address 192.168.51.232 255.255.255.0                                  
 ip access-group DHCP out                                                 
 ip nat inside                                                            
 ip virtual-reassembly in                                                 
 duplex auto                                                              
 speed auto                                                               
 no mop enabled                                                           
!
```

(the VLANs are for VLAN tag based QoS on the switches in case anyone wonders)

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add any static routes or routing protocols to these two routers.
Both networks are directly connected to the routers so they should be able to route traffic between the two by default. If it does not work it's not going to be a routing issue but rather something else such as NAT.